# Invoice-like example to understand reactivity of nested object in arrays. Should I use a store for this?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store, svelte-2

I'm trying my best to understand the idiomatic way to create an Invoice-like form with Svelte 3.

My **REPL** is here: https://svelte.dev/repl/7aca36569aea49bba38e5fb8b1b0835b?version=3.24.1.

**QUESTIONS**:

1. Is this a good way to do it? Should I use a store perhaps?
2. Is there a way to update amountDue when I change `qty` and `price` of my rows? (I know I can do it with `rows = rows` but it seems to me a bit not-idiomatic way, am I wrong?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need a more complete answer:

1. No need to use a store. That's normally the case for when you want to communicate several components.
2. As proposed earlier, you should bind the `row` value to the Row's `row` prop. You can use the shortcut `bind:row` as an alias of `bind:row={row}`.
3. *Minor:* The logic to calculate `amountDue` total seems flawed as it ignores the row quantity to calculate the total price.

Here's a working REPL with the desired behavior: https://svelte.dev/repl/78fa09646005441a85061e6edf9886f9?version=3.24.1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use a store (probably useful for a large tree of components)

For the second question, You just need to do a component binding

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings

```
{#each rows as row}
    <Row bind:row />
{:else}
    Still no rows.
{/each}
```

Notice how we use the bind keyword instead of just passing the prop